# Which dry run for quicksort is the correct one? Confused

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I'm preparing for an exam and currently learning again for quicksort.

Say I'm supposed to do a quicksort dry run for the array

```
8,6,2,7,1,4,3,5
```

My friend say I do it wrong because in quicksort it will move the index and swap at the same time. So basically in the steps I did below, I can skip the steps where I only move `i, j`. So he say I need to move and swap same time. Can you say if he is right? I think it's all good.. Please tell me because I'm not sure for exam now...

I have index `i` it will go through array till it finds greater element than pivot element. `j` is index for lower than pivot element. and P is pivotelement. `||` means the element is in correct position aka sorted.

```
8,6,2,7,1,4,3,5
i           j P

3,6,2,7,1,4,8,5
  i       j   P

3,4,2,7,1,6,8,5
  i       j   P

3,4,2,7,1,6,8,5
      i j     P

3,4,2,1,7,6,8,5
      j i     P

3,4,2,1,|5|,6,8,7
      j  P      i

3,4,2,1,|5|,6,8,7
i   j P

3,4,2, 1, |5|,6,8,7
i      Pj

1,4,2, 3, |5|,6,8,7
i      Pj

1,4,2,3,|5|,6,8,7
  i j P

1,2,4,3,|5|,6,8,7
  j i P

1,2,|3|,|4|,|5|,6,8,7
  j  P   i

1, 2, |3|,|4|,|5|,6,8,7
i  Pj

1, 2, |3|,|4|,|5|,6,8,7
j  Pi

|1|, |2|,|3|,|4|,|5|,6,8,7
 j   Pi

|1|,|2|,|3|,|4|,|5|,6,8,7
                    i j P

|1|,|2|,|3|,|4|,|5|,6,8,7
                    j i P

|1|,|2|,|3|,|4|,|5|,|6|,|7|,|8|
                     j   P   i
```

This is his version. Much shorter than me because he doesn't move index in an extra step like me.. So he has twice as less steps than me. What you think is correct?

[image]

Comment: How can we possibly know which answer your lecturer expects you to give during the exam?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well from exam point of view, I think your version seems more appropriate, because you in exams **its better to elaborate each and every step**.

In your friend's version, the examiner will not be very much pleased with the answer as there is no indication of `left(i)` and `right(j)` iterators and the `pivot` element.

From implementation point of view, **both of you are basically doing the same thing**, its just that you show the moving of iterators as well as swapping of values separately, but that does not change the **semantics** of the algorithm.

If you carefully see, its the same thing:

**YOU**

```
swap(array[i] , array[j])
i = i + 1
j = j - 1
```

**FRIEND**

```
swap(array[i++] , array[j--])
```

Comment: Note also that the OP indicates the pivot element, which the friend does not seem to do.

Comment: Great thank you for reading through my long answer and helping! :) Now I'm sure about quicksort in my exam.